# Why dotenv retur undefined when .env file exist?

Tags: node.js, undefined, dotenv

I have following problem. ".env" file does not exist. When I unzip .env file and I try to read parameteres from it I receive "undefined". When I run again my app and .env file exist then it works well. Why I receive "undefined" when I the file is there after unzip?

```
I have following function:

function envRead(){
require ('dotenv').config({path:'c:/ImageDISM/.env'});

const fi = process.env.FOLDER_IMAGES;
const fd = process.env.FOLDER_DATA;
const fn = process.env.FILE;
const dbn = process.env.DB;

return {
        fi,
        fd,
        fn,
        dbn
        };
}

module.exports = {envRead}

part of app.js
.
.
.
console.log(fileArgs[1]);

extract(`c:\\ImageDISM\\${fileArgs[1]}`, {dir:"c:\\ImageDISM/"}, function (err) {
   // handle err
   console.log(err);
})

sleep(10000).then(() => {
    fs.access("c:/ImageDISM/.env", fs.constants.F_OK | fs.constants.W_OK, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(
          `"c:/ImageDISM/.env" ${err.code === 'ENOENT' ? 'does not exist' : 'is read-only'}`);
      } else {
        console.log("c:/ImageDISM/.env exists, and it is writable");
      }

          fi = resultenvr.fi;
          fd = resultenvr.fd;
          fn = resultenvr.fn;
          dbn = resultenvr.dbn;
         console.log(`image adresare: ${fi}`);
         console.log(`cilovy adresar: ${fd}`);
         console.log(`jmeno souboru: ${fn}`);
         console.log(`database: ${dbn}`);
         });
})
.
.
```

Comment: I think you need to wait for the file extraction to be complete. I also don't see where do you use `envRead` function.

Comment: const resultenvr = envr.envRead();
          fi = resultenvr.fi;
          fd = resultenvr.fd;
          fn = resultenvr.fn;
          dbn = resultenvr.dbn;

How to wait?

Comment: Okay, I think you have that line missing in the snippet you shared. Have you tried moving your all fs.access code, inside the extract callback?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, it des not help. When the file exist before run app.js it works well but when I "create" the file by unzip (extract) then does not work.